# How to Change Row Color With JavaScript in Condition?

Tags: javascript

For some reasons i using this javaScript code for highlight rows. I need add condition to this code block. Something like this :

```
 function onGridViewRowSelected(rowIdx, rowIdx2) {
   //bring value via get control and assign
var selRow = getSelectedRow(rowIdx);
//Check Current Row is null or not
if (curSelRow != null) {
   //..TRIED THIS ROW
    if (curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = '#red') {
        //do nothing..
    } else {


        curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
    }
}
//come to here if not in condition and check selected row is null or not
if (null != selRow) {
//if in condition ..
    curSelRow = selRow;
    //change current selected row background color
    curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = '#ababab';
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question?  Your javascript has several issues.  For starters, `if` conditions should use `==` or `===`, not `=`.

Comment: ... and `#red` won't work. You need to remove the #.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your question though, but your js code has a bug:

```
if (curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = '#red')  // WRONG, u can't do this
if (curSelRow.style.backgroundColor == '#red') // use color codes instead ( for red = #ff0000 ) or just red..
```